# C# application to intercept out-going web requests from a computer

Tags: c#, webrequest

I am looking for a way to implement a simple C# application which can intercept out-going web requests from a computer so that I can allow or block the request depending on which website user is trying to access.
It is a kind of parental control application.
I just don't know which C# class would be able to do such intercepting and which steps would involve configuring it / making it works.
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to achive that would be creating your own HTTP proxy, for example by taking something like http://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddlercore.
In such way all the HTTP/HTTPS traffic would go through your proxy and you would be albe to control what can pass through and what can not, that is how corporations control what their employees can access from company's networks.